# Function not retaining values in an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, filelist

So I have a function that loops through files in a directory, pulls the designated arrays out of each file, and stacks them in one large array next to one another.

```
def Graph(files,directory):
    pattern = "{}.fits".format(files)
    x = array([])
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(directory),pattern):
        data = pyfits.getdata(filename)
        x1 = data.field('table')
        x = hstack((x,x1))

    plot(x,y) #where y would also be defined as data retrieved in the loop
```

When the function leaves the loop, it clears the large array (x) completely. Any clue to why this is happening?

I need to get data from a list of files and combine all their data into a single array, and plot that data. ( I will be plotting it versus another array "y" that will be created in the same fashion.)

Comment: Your edit does not make clear *why* you need `x` to stay or why you can't return `x` at the end of the function. What *else* do you need `x` *for*?

Comment: Or is your plot not working? What is going wrong, what did you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: The plot isn't working. Everything in that code box is with thing Graph function. The problem is the array 'x' is getting cleared when it leaves the loops, even though it is still inside of the function. Same for y. So when I go to plot, I just get a blank plot. I've ran this script without defining the code under a function and it worked fine.

Comment: ^ As in, if you take away the def function() line, it works, but when it doesn't work when it's there.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you created `x` in the function, when the function exits it goes out of scope and is automatically cleaned up.

Return it at the end of the function and store the result:

```
def Graph(files,directory):
    pattern = "{}.fits".format(files)
    x = array([])
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(directory),pattern):
        data = pyfits.getdata(filename)
        x1 = data.field('table')
        x = hstack((x,x1))

    plot(x,y) #where y would also be defined as data retrieved in the loop

    return x

x = Graph(files, directory)
```

Comment: Oh, I understand. Now with that, wouldn't you want to return x before the plot function, in order to plot the values in that array?

Comment: @TimurCetindag: `return` exits the function at that point, and `plot()` would not be called. You can return `(x, y)`, store both (`x, y = Graph(...)`), and *then* call `plot(x, y)` outside the function perhaps?

Comment: Well I don't want to do anything outside of the function. I need it all to be internal: data retrieval and plotting.

Is there any way store that data without exiting the function?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please add that to your question.

Comment: I added it to the main question. 

What I need to do is get data from a list of files and combine all that data into a single array, x. I will do this for another array, y, as well. Then, I just need to plot that data.

Comment: nvm I got it working. I was just calling the function incorrectly. Silly me. Stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Also others already pointed out, you have to `return` the array you read in, in order to use it later. Some additional comments:

- It would be more elegant if the routine only read the data, and you would plot it after the routine returned it.
- Do not use hstack in a loop as it creates copies. Either use the `fromfile` or `genfromtxt` routines from numpy or at least create a list in your loop and convert this to an array once the loop finished. The same is valid for y, if you obtain it in a similar way:

  ```
  def readfiles(files, directory):
      "Returns x and y values read from files in a given directory."
      pattern = "{}.fits".format(files)
      tmpx = []
      tmpy = []
      for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(directory),pattern):
          data = pyfits.getdata(filename)
          tmpx.append(data.field('table'))
          tmpy.append(...)    # Retrieve your y data
      x = hstack(tmpx)
      y = hstack(tmpy)
      return x, y

  # Main program
  x, y = readfiles("test", "testdir")
  plot(x, y)
  ```